# Django - How do I add the user I created to my group?

Tags: python, django

I'm using [django-groups-manager.](https://github.com/vittoriozamboni/django-groups-manager)

I logged in as a user. When I register another user, how do I register another user under the group name I belong to? How do I add members to the group?

**forms.py**

```
class CalisanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    member = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Çalışan Adı')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'member',
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
def calisan(request):
    form = CalisanForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        member = form.cleaned_data['member']
        member = Member.objects.create(first_name=member)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'accounts/calisan/calisan.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: you may belong to multiple groups, you need to decide which one(s) to pick for that new user.
you can get your Django user with request.user
to assign a member to a group, it is in the README of the django-group-manager repo

Comment: No, he'il be a member of a single group. When I sign up for the site, I create my group. After logging in, I go to the add user page and create a new user. The user I created will be automatically included in my group. Can you give an example through code?

Comment: @witcher you cannot guarantee that a user will only have 1 group. You would need to define your own custom user model to add this retriction

Comment: However, when I register, I write the group name, and at the end of the registration, both my group was created and I joined the group. While I can do this in the registration process, how can I not in the above problem. The only difference is that I will not form a group, but I will join an existing group.